# Arr::get() vs data_get() in Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5, facade

With `data_get()` helper function, we can get value of a nested array using dot `.` notation as following:

```
$my_arr = [
    'a' => ['lower' => 'aa', 'upper' => 'AAA',], 
    'b' => ['lower' => 'bbb', 'upper' => 'BBBBB',],
];
```

Thus, I can get lower `a` by doing this.

```
data_get($my_arr, 'a.lower');
```

And you also do the following.

```
Arr::get('a.lower');
```

In case I just want to get only the first level of the array. I just can do both:

```
data_get($my_arr, 'a');
```

OR

```
Arr::get($my_arr, 'a');
```

Which one do you recommend me and why? I just want to keep improving my Laravel experience and get good advice from senior developers to choose the best options at the moment.

Comment: It depends upon the use case in context.

Comment: Above is my use case, get element from the array by array index key. Or it does not matter which one to use?

Comment: The major difference is either your variable is an array or object. `data_get` will check if `$my_arr` is an object or not whereas `Arr::get` would assume it is an array. So if your data is an array, you can use `Arr::get` to save up some unnecessary checks.

Comment: @OConnor if your usage is just limited to above ways of using it, `data_get()` is an overkill. `data_get()` also performs wildcard matches.

Comment: For both of you, that's the answer I am looking for. I did not think about that. Just now after reading your answer. thank!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It depends on the context to decide which one to use.

## 1. Wildcard matching

If you need to use wildcard in your index, you have to go with `data_get` as `Arr::get` does not support wildcards.

Example:

```
Arr::get($my_arr, '*.lower'); // null
data_get($my_arr, '*.lower'); // ["aa", "bbb"]
```

## 2. Variable Type

`Arr::get` simply assumes that your variable is an array. Therefore, if you use an object, you have to go with `data_get`. If, however you are sure your variable is an array and you don't need wildcards, you should proceed with `Arr::get` to avoid unnecessary checks from `data_get` that evaluates to see if your variable is an object or array.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `array_get()` method, it's the same as `Arr::get()`. Of course if you have laravel/helpers package installed.

Check the `./vendor/laravel/helpers/src/helpers.php` file.