# How can I access specific object properties in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, object, eloquent

I tried using data_get() function, But it doesn't return me anything.

Can any one help me to access data array from the below object in laravel??

Any information regarding this would be appreciated. Thank You!!

> **$data = data_get($object,'data');**

```
 $object = {
  "success": true,
  "message": "Something....",
  "data": [
   
       {
          "id": 9,
          "name": "name1"
       },
       {
          "id": 10,
          "name": "name2"
       }

   ]
}
```

Comment: you can check it :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55185531/arrget-vs-data-get-in-laravel-5-7

Comment: That doesn't look like an object. That doesn't even look like PHP

Answer (score 3):

You can convert the json object into an array using **json_decode()**.

```
$newObject = json_decode($object, true);
```

From here, you can simply access it like

`$data = $newObject['data'];`

`$message = $newObject['message'];`

Answer (score 1):

$data = json_decode($object, true);
$data->message;